# Flutter barcode_scan change color

Tags: flutter, colors, barcode

I am trying to change the color of the flutter [barcode scanner](https://pub.dev/packages/barcode_scan):
[image]

I want to change the yellow and the gray color of the top bar.

I already tried to do something with the ScanOptions:

```
void barcode() async {

  var options = ScanOptions(
    
  );

  var result = await BarcodeScanner.scan();
  print(result.rawContent);

}
```

I couldn't find anything for this in the internet.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this [barcode scanner](https://pub.dev/packages/barcode_scan) does not have any options for changing the color of Option menu

but if you want you can change it from android manifest:
add theme in the application tag of manifest and change the color of popupMenu from theme

```
 <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="My App"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
...
```

Comment: hi, what exactly do I have to do to change the theme? And would this also change the colors on iPhones?